Combine data at fixed location from multiple Excel files into one Excel
I have data in multiple excel files at exact same location which I need to combine into one file. But there is data above and below it as well which I don't need.
INPUT:
    File 1
    Row 1-10 - Not useful data
    Row 11-12 - Useful data
    Row 13-20 Not useful data

    File 2
    Row 1-10 - Not useful data
    Row 11-12 - Useful data
    Row 13-20 Not useful data


OUTPUT

    File 1 Row 11
    File 1 Row 12
    File 2 Row 11
    File 2 Row 12

I am trying to combine data using Power Query. I can successfully read all the data but I don't how to remove the data which I don't need. Basically I need to transform the data of one excel and apply the same steps to all the other excel. which I can't figure out inside power query.
If I use Combine and transform then all the excels get combined into one and I can't remove top and bottom rows. And if I select one file and then transform then data from only that file loads.
Also I have 100s of such files which can't be edited now. So it can't be manual.

After you read in each Excel, and before you combine them, you would apply the Table.Range function to retain rows 11 and 12 from each file.

Where and how? There are Combine to, Combine and load, combine and transform. I assume in Combine and transform, but how?

I think you'll find that command in the UI in the select rows area. Show your existing code from the advanced editor for a better idea.
